# How to make a javascript clock countdown on every row on a php table?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table in my website which adds a new row every time a user submits in a request through a form. the problem with my current code is that only the first row does a proper count down and the other rows show no values at all...

Please kindly assist me in making sure that every row shows a working countdown clock.

Below is my javascript clock count down

```
<script>
function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
  var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
  var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
  var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime){
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock(){
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if(t.total<=0){
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock,1000);
}

var deadline = "<?php echo $result ?>";

initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
</script>
```

Below is my table which gets data from my database

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<hr />
<br>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
if(!empty($records))
{
foreach($records as $rec)
{ 
?>
<tr>
<span><h6>Title Name:<?php echo $rec['name']; ?></h6></span> <br>
Your request was made in

<?php //code that converts time for javascript count down time
$start_date = new DateTime($rec['date']);
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($rec['confirm_date']));
?>    

<?php //code that converts time for javascript count down time

$date = new DateTime($rec['confirm_date']);
$result = $date->format('F d Y H:i:s');
if ($result) 
{
} 
else 
{ 
echo "Unknown Time";
} 
?> 
<?php echo $rec['date']; ?><br>
Your request typw will <?php echo $rec['request_type']; ?><br><br>

<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />
<br>
<?php }} ?>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is this going to be the same counter for all rows, or will they all have individual counters with different start/end values? // For starters, you’ll want to switch out querySelector for querySelectorAll, so that you get all elements of a specific class, instead of just the first one. Of course that also means that you will have to _loop_ over those elements, to assign the new content to each one individually.

Comment: Use `class` instead of `id` for your `clockdiv` elements and loop over them using `querySelectorAll`

Comment: each row should have a new counter for every row...

Comment: may i ask how do i loop over them using querySelectorAll ?

Comment: @Chazz Use a for loop.